# pgfplots: undefined control secquence in a foreach loop

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

I am getting an undefined control sequence when using `\col` in a `\foreach` loop.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeyscurrentkey ->\col
```

---

```
\documentclass[tikz, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 500,
    no marks,
    xlabel = $\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel = $\scriptstyle y$
    ]
    \foreach \u/\col in {1/red, 2/blue, 3/OliveGreen}{
      \addplot+[\col, domain = -4:4, variable = \v]
      ({(exp(\u) + exp(-\u)) / 2 * cos(deg(v))},
      {(exp(\u) - exp(-\u)) / 2 * sin(deg(v))});
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And also, how can I use `\addlegendentry` for the plot with a loop?

Comment: have a look at [PGFplots foreach equivalent to TikZ's with multiple variables separated by a slash](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17638)

Comment: As a work-around: `\expandafter\addplot\expandafter+\expandafter[\col, dom…`. `pgfplots` doesn’t process the content linear but firstly collects everything and then evaluates it. At this point `\col` isn’t defined anymore.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks that worked.  Do you know how I can use `\addlegenentry` when using `\foreach`?  This part of the question is located below the code.

Comment: @dustin You can use `\addlegendentryexpanded{$u =\u$}` instead of `\addlegendentry`. Same problem, different solution.

Comment: @percusse I using Qrrbrbirlbel answer which isn't part of that thread.

Comment: @dustin They do the same thing with `\edef`