# Problems using \addlegendentry in a loop with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, siunitx, loops, legend

I have some spectra to plot, which I exported from the [Siemens Xray toolbox](https://w9.siemens.com/cms/oemproducts/Home/X-rayToolbox/spektrum/Pages/radIn.aspx), which works nicely with `pgfplots`.

Since these are multiple files that look the same I think I can do it with a for loop, which also works.

But now I have problems with adding a legend entry, since that does not work. When I use a `\addlegendentry` with `siunitx` I cannot compile the copde below, I get informed that the

> Argument of \add@accent has an extra }.

This becomes more clear when I don't use `siunitx` but just want to get the values (commented line in the example below), then there's no number in the legend, only a nice k with a hat (no idea how it's called `:)`).

When I don't do use a `for`-loop, but add the plots manually for each one it works. But since in the final figure I have to plot more than 20 spectra (all much bigger than the one in the example) I'd like to do it in a loop, ideally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Xray-Spectrum_040.txt}
9 2.23512e-015
10 2.18948e-009
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{Xray-Spectrum_046.txt}
9 1.98718e-015
10 1.56485e-009
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \foreach \v in {40,46} {
        \addplot table {Xray-Spectrum_0\v.txt};
        \addlegendentry{\v kv}
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Related

I had to rename the files from `Xray-Spectrum_046kV.txt` to `Xray-Spectrum_046.txt` to make it work. Is there a way I can get the variable to be evaluated in the middle of the filename?

Comment: I am not sure if it is related, but you may want to try `addlegendentryexpanded{}` instead. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317015/1280

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code does the job. For the problem relative to the macro expansion inside `\addlegendentry` see this answer: [PGFplots foreach equivalent to TikZ's with multiple variables separated by a slash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17817/31093). For the macro in the file name you can simply leave a white space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{Xray-Spectrum_040kv.txt}
9 2.23512e-015
10 2.18948e-009
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{Xray-Spectrum_046kv.txt}
9 1.98718e-015
10 1.56485e-009
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \foreach \v in {40,46} {
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\addlegendentry{\SI{\v}{\kilo\volt}}}
        \addplot table {Xray-Spectrum_0\v kv.txt};
        \temp
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I happen to have stumbled upon this very issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For very strange reasons, a `\foreach` statement inside `axis` seems to want as argument only already defined macros. You're using `\v` that's an accent macro and this “explains” the strange error message.

Unfortunately, it appears that `\SI` doesn't behave well inside `\addlegendentry` and so some trick as the one mentioned by Red has to be used.

I suggest to define your macro for these cases, so not to incur, at least, in puzzling error messages. Then you can abstract the method defining an `\addlegendentrySI` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newcommand\xyz{} % in order to use a different macro
\newcommand{\addlegendentrySI}[3][]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\addlegendentry{\SI[#1]{#2}{#3}}}\x
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{Xray-Spectrum_040.txt}
9 2.23512e-015
10 2.18948e-009
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{Xray-Spectrum_046.txt}
9 1.98718e-015
10 1.56485e-009
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \foreach \xyz in {40,46} {
    \addplot table {Xray-Spectrum_0\xyz.txt};
    \addlegendentrySI[color=red]{\xyz}{\kilo\volt}
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is surely handier than writing several `\edef\temo{...}` lines. I added also the `color=red` option just to show that an optional argument can be used.

[image]

Comment: Since I only use one loop, writing `\edef...` once is not too much of a hassle, but redefining it to a command is also a nice idea. I'll use this when I have to use this workaround multiple times in the same plot `:)`