# How does PGFplots calculate trig functions?

Tags: pgfplots

In plotting the graph from my [last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238266/plotting-a-graph-with-several-values-of-a-parameter) I have discovered that the plots I'm getting from PGFplots are not entirely correct.  I was attempting to plot `(4.9/(w^2))*(cosh(w*x)-cos(w*x))` for multiple values of `w`.  With the help of the users 1010011010 and Enthusiastic Student I was able to get good looking plots -- that is until I checked what I should be getting with WolframAlpha.

As `w` in my above formula goes to `0`, the function should asymptote to `4.9*x^2` from above.  That is not what the data is showing.  Using this code, which is essentially just 1010011010's in the link above,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\mycolone{yellow}
\def\mycoltwo{green}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(.5,-.2)}, anchor=north}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-0.5,ymax=100,no markers, grid=both, samples=100, restrict y to domain=0:1000]
\foreach \w in {5,10,...,100} {\edef\tmp{\noexpand\addplot[\mycolone!\w!\mycoltwo, domain=-10:10]}
\pgfmathparse{\w/100}
\edef\x{\pgfmathresult}
\tmp{(4.9/((\w/100)^2))*(cosh(\w*x/100)-cos(\w*x/100))};
\edef\legendentry{\noexpand\addlegendentry{$\omega = \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\x}$}};
\legendentry}
\addplot[draw=red, domain=-10:10] {4.9*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following plots.
[image]
Here the red plot is `(4.9)*x^2`.

For reference, here's what WolframAlpha gives me for the highest and lowest values of `w` plotted above (`w=0.05` and `w=1`) and the plot of `(4.9)*x^2`:
[image]

It's hard to tell, but if I remove the `4.9*x^2` plot you can see that the plot with `w=0.05` follows it pretty much exactly.

This is very different behavior from the first image above.  So my question is how does PGFplots compute things like `exp`, `cosh`, and `cos`, and how can I get a better approximation in the future?

Comment: Try with `cos(\w*x/100 r)` to convert radians to degrees for the trig function.

Comment: @PaulGessler Ah.  OK.  What a simple fix.  I hadn't even considered that -- I don't ever use degrees.  So thanks.  If you want to write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigonometric functions of `pgf` assume inputs in of degrees. To input an angle in radians, use the special `r` operator: replace `cos(\w*x/100)` with `cos(\w*x/100 r)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\mycolone{yellow}
\def\mycoltwo{green}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12,every axis legend/.append style={at={(.5,-.2)}, anchor=north}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-0.5,ymax=100,no markers, grid=both, samples=100, restrict y to domain=0:1000]
\foreach \w in {5,10,...,100} {\edef\tmp{\noexpand\addplot[\mycolone!\w!\mycoltwo, domain=-10:10]}
\pgfmathparse{\w/100}
\edef\x{\pgfmathresult}
\tmp{(4.9/((\w/100)^2))*(cosh(\w*x/100)-cos(\w*x/100 r))};
\edef\legendentry{\noexpand\addlegendentry{$\omega = \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\x}$}};
\legendentry}
\addplot[draw=red, domain=-10:10] {4.9*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, with `pgfplots` v1.11 or newer, a new key `trig format plots` allows us to change the angle format for all `\addplot` commands in-scope of the key setting<sup>1</sup>. Here, I use `trig format plots=rad` at the top level to change the behavior for the whole document, but it could also be applied per-axis or per-plot. Note that this will only affect `pgfplots`' `\addplot` commands, not any plain Ti*k*Z code with trig functions. Additionally, this key is somewhat experimental and may not work properly with more exotic axis types such as `polar` and `smithchart`. The package manual mentions that it has been tested only for default axes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\mycolone{yellow}
\def\mycoltwo{green}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.12,
  every axis legend/.append style={at={(.5,-.2)}, anchor=north},
  trig format plots=rad,
} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-0.5,ymax=100,no markers, grid=both, samples=100, restrict y to domain=0:1000]
\foreach \w in {5,10,...,100} {\edef\tmp{\noexpand\addplot[\mycolone!\w!\mycoltwo, domain=-10:10]}
\pgfmathparse{\w/100}
\edef\x{\pgfmathresult}
\tmp{(4.9/((\w/100)^2))*(cosh(\w*x/100)-cos(\w*x/100))};
\edef\legendentry{\noexpand\addlegendentry{$\omega = \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=2]{\x}$}};
\legendentry}
\addplot[draw=red, domain=-10:10] {4.9*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both methods give the correct result:

[image]

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to [Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1537/christian-feuers%C3%A4nger), the `pgfplots` author himself, for pointing this new method out to me in a comment.

Comment: Related: recent versions of `pgfplots` allow to say `trig format plots=rad` to switch the default format from degrees to radians.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger cool, I did not know about this! I'll add a note about this to the answer. Thank you!