# PGFPlots: How to add a legend entry from a macro into a foreach loop?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

I'm doing a stacked bar plot where each plot is taken from a different column of the same file, and I have the list of column names I want to use in a macro:

```
\newcommand\tools{tool1, tool2, tool3, tool4}
```

Then I use a foreach loop to add the single plots:

```
\foreach \tool in \tools {
   \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y={\tool}] {file.dat};
}
```

It is perfectly working but then I want to add a legend, with an entry
for each plot, but this is not working:

```
\begin{axis}[legend entries={\tools}]
% ....
\end{axis}
```

What I get instead is a *single* entry with all the tools as written in the macro, including the commas:

[image]

So it seems the macro is expanded too late or something like that.
The same happens if I use the `\legend` command in the axis instead of the `legend entries` option.

I also tried to manually add the entries with `\addlegendentry` inside the loop, but it doesn't work either:

```
\foreach \tool in \tools {
   \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y={\tool}] {file.dat};
   \addlegendentry{\tool}
}
```

In this case I get a compile error:

```
./experiments.tex:74: Undefined control sequence. [    \end{axis}]
```

So how can I get the legend entries from the `\tools` macro?

Comment: Please provide small document, which we can copy and compile. With this the answer to your question would be make more easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
\foreach \tool in \tools {
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y={\tool}] {file.dat};
    \expandafter\addlegendentry\expandafter{\tool}
}
```

This error is caused by the way TikZ reads the code before executing the for loop.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the `\tempVar` trick is not needed, it works for me with only the two `\expandafter` using the original `\tool` variable. May I edit the answer?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes you may.

Comment: It worked! By the way, in case someone else tried it, removing the braces around `\tool` after the last `\expandafter` causes an `Undefined control sequence` error. Writing them, as you did in your answer, is the only way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, version 1.13 (the one I'm using, I don't know if the same holds for previous releases) provides the command `\addlegendentryexpanded[<opt>]{<arg>}`.

The code therefore becomes:

```
\foreach \tool in \tools {
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y={\tool}] {file.dat};
    \addlegendentryexpanded{\tool}
}
```

See section 4.9.4 of the `pgfplots` manual for reference.