# PGFPlots: How to add xticklabels from a variable or macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros

I have a branching in my figure according to a parameter and I would like to change the x tick labels according to that, having them stored in a variable. I have found a [similar solution for legend entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289846/pgfplots-how-to-add-a-legend-entry-from-a-macro-into-a-foreach-loop) but I haven't found anything similar for the tick labels.

My naive approach was:

```
\def \legendLabels {a, b, c}
\begin{axis} [
xticklabels=\legendLabels]
```

This creates one big label from the string in the variable which is used as the first label on the axis.
I think that another solution would be to add another if-else and create a different axis but that is quite ugly. I have also tried inserting `\ifthenelse` directly in the `xticklabels` but it does the same effect as the previous attempt.

Comment: `\begin{axis}[xticklabels/.expanded=\legendLabels]` although in this case `\begin{axis}[xticklabels/.expand once=\legendLabels]` should be sufficient.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629627/ I suppose?

Comment: Thank you @HenriMenke, that's it!!

Comment: Yea, my bad @TorbjørnT. I didn't notice this one.