# Use \macro within xcolor expression

Tags: pgfplots, color

So this seems to be impossible:

```
OrangeRed!\c!white
```

with `\c` being any kind of `\def` formula, or precisely in my case, with a `\pgfmathsetmacro`. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% TIKZ & PGF
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, decorations.shapes, decorations.markings, shapes, patterns}

% % % % % % % % CIRCLES % % % % % % % %
% #1 angle
% #2 ray
% #3 shift
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{circleX}{3}
{%
    \pgfmathparse{#3 + #2*cos(deg(#1))}%
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{circleY}{3}
{%
    \pgfmathparse{#3 + #2*sin(deg(#1))}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}


        \tikzset{
            small dot/.style={fill=black, circle, scale=2}
        }

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\halfPi}{.5*pi}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\twoPi}{2*pi}

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yshift}{0.25}

        \begin{axis}[axis x line=center, axis y line=none, width=.5\textwidth, axis equal,
                     xtick={0,\halfPi,...,\twoPi}, xticklabels={$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$}]


            \foreach \i in {0.25,0.5,...,1} { %
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{(1.2-\i)*100}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xshift}{\i*2*pi}

                %\addplot[OrangeRed!\c!white -> nope
                %\addplot[color=OrangeRed!\c!white -> nope
                %\addplot[color={OrangeRed!\c!white} -> nope
                %\addplot[color/.expanded=OrangeRed!\c!white -> nope

                \addplot[color=OrangeRed!50!white, samples=80, domain=0:2*pi]
                    ({circleX(x,\r,\xshift)},{circleY(x,\r,\r+\yshift)});
            }

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to use a macro within an `xcolor` expression without the need of a `\definecolor{colorname}{rgb|cmyk|...}{color stuff definition}`?

Comment: This should work, can you test `color=OrangeRed!\c!white` or `color/.expanded=OrangeRed!\c!white`? There may be problems with `xcolor` and different color schemes (`OrangeRed` is not available by default) or PGFPlots or `\foreach` or ... Can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and the error message you get or what does not work as expected?

Comment: your solution seems to be inefficient, I added the MWE. Regarding the errors, with `OrangeRed!\c!white`, I have `Missing \endcsname inserted`, with `color=OrangeRed!\c!white`, I have `Missing number, treated as zero` and with `color/.expanded=OrangeRed!\c!white`, I have `pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/color' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to expand `\c` (but I'd use a different name) before `\addplot` sees it:

```
\documentclass{article}

% TIKZ & PGF
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, decorations.shapes, decorations.markings, shapes, patterns}

% % % % % % % % CIRCLES % % % % % % % %
% #1 angle
% #2 ray
% #3 shift
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{circleX}{3}
 {%
  \pgfmathparse{#3 + #2*cos(deg(#1))}%
 }
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{circleY}{3}
 {%
  \pgfmathparse{#3 + #2*sin(deg(#1))}%
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{small dot/.style={fill=black, circle, scale=2}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\halfPi}{.5*pi}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\twoPi}{2*pi}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yshift}{0.25}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=none,
  width=.5\textwidth,
  axis equal,
  xtick={0,\halfPi,...,\twoPi},
  xticklabels={$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$}
]
\foreach \i in {0.25,0.5,...,1} {%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{(1.2-\i)*100}
  \edef\mycol{OrangeRed!\mycol}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xshift}{\i*2*pi}
  \expandafter\addplot\expandafter[%
    \mycol!white,
    samples=80,
    domain=0:2*pi
  ]({circleX(x,\r,\xshift)},{circleY(x,\r,\r+\yshift)});
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is the best I've found but I don't know if you'll find it easy enough. It's more or less the same effort required to define a color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yshift}{1}
\foreach \i in {0.25,0.5,...,1} {%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{(1.2-\i)*100}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cx}{\i*2*pi}
  \xdef\doplot{\noexpand\addplot[color=red!\c!yellow, samples=80]}
  \doplot ({\cx + \a*cos(deg(x))},{\a + \yshift + \a*sin(deg(x))});
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

---

EDIT: This answered the original question.

This works OK, unless I'm missing something:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\c{50}
Text in a {\color{red!\c!yellow} fancy} color.
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: my bad, I should have been posting the full code I'm working on, see my edit...

Answer (score 6):

It is known that PGFPlots and `\foreach`s don’t go so nicely together because PGFPlots doesn’t process the plots firstly and then later draws them. (See [PGFplots foreach equivalent to TikZ's with multiple variables separated by a slash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17638/16595) for more information and explanations of the author of PGFPlot himself.) The package provides the macros

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{<list>}{<body>}
```

and

```
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped <list of variables> in {<list>}{<body>}
```

The manual even explains the problems and the usage of `\edef\temp` to “pre-expand” macros.

In your example however, we can avoid this if we postpone the calculation of the color until it is actually plotted/drawn by moving the calculation inside the plot (the `\xshift` macro is properly expanded in all cases since PGFPlots expects there to be things that needs to be expanded):

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.25,0.5,...,1}{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xshift}{#1*2*pi}
  \addplot[
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro\col{(1.2-#1)*100},
    color=OrangeRed!\col!white, samples=80, domain=0:2*pi]
      ({circleX(x,\r,\xshift)},{circleY(x,\r,\r+\yshift)});
}
```

With my [`qrr.misc`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibraryqrr.misc.code.tex) library and its `.pgfmath strcat` handler you can even do

```
color/.pgfmath strcat={"OrangeRed!",(1.2-#1)*100,"!white"}
```

The `forest` package provides similar handlers (`.wrap pgfmath arg`), though they fail here, too.

Comment: Yeah, `pgfkeys/handlers`, never used that but it was popin' around while I was seeking a solution. The `/utils/exec` portion of your lib can hold as much stuff that I want?

Comment: The `/utils/exec` key is not mine but defined either by TikZ or PGF and simply executes TeX code as it is given to it. Similar how `\pgfextra` can be used for TikZ paths which doesn't have PGFPlots equivalent as far as I know. The `.pgfmath strcat` simply evaluates `\pgfmathparse{strcat(<arg>)}` and forwards its result to the key. The [`strcat`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=strcat+user%3Ame) function is also defined in `qrr.misc` and concatenates its arguments. The `"` are needed to use stuff as text and not let it be evaluated by PGFmath (see PGF manual).