# Problem with tikz foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I am using a foreach loop to add plots to an axis environment and want each plot to have its own color.
To achieve this I tried the following:

```
\foreach \x/\barcolor in {1/red, 2/green, 3/blue, 4/gray}{
    \addplot[fill=\barcolor] table[x=key,y expr={\thisrowno{\x}/\thisrowno{6}}] {data.dat};
}
```

But somehow there is a problem with the `\barcolor` variable. If I use `fill=blue` the loop runs perfectly fine, but obviously all bars are blue. Unfolding the loop and manually adding the four plot is working fine too:

```
\addplot[fill=red] table[x=key,y expr={\thisrowno{1}/\thisrowno{6}}] {data.dat};
\addplot[fill=green] table[x=key,y expr={\thisrowno{2}/\thisrowno{6}}] {data.dat};
\addplot[fill=blue] table[x=key,y expr={\thisrowno{3}/\thisrowno{6}}] {data.dat};
\addplot[fill=gray] table[x=key,y expr={\thisrowno{4}/\thisrowno{6}}] {data.dat};
```

I cannot figure the problem with my loop and hope you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I suspect you need `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\addplot[fill=\barcolor]}\x` instead of `\addplot[fill=\barcolor]`

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thank you very much for this comment. Can your please add an answer and give some explanations to your code.

Comment: or `\addplot[fill/.expanded=\barcolor]`

Comment: @percusse Which is much nicer!

Comment: But this does not seem to wor for me. Can you explain the problem of my original code and what was your attempt to fix it?

Comment: After reading this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla related question, I understand the problem. Though, I still do net get why the solution of percusse does not work. According to the pgf manual it should do exactly what I want it to do (p. 663).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `cycle list` for the colors.

Example:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
key 1 2 3 4 5 6
1   1 2 3 4 5 6
2   2 3 4 5 6 7
3   7 8 2 1 3 8
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  enlarge x limits={abs=30pt},
  cycle list={red,green,blue,gray}
]
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}{
\addplot+[fill,draw=black] table [x=key, y expr={\thisrowno{\x}/\thisrowno{6}}] {data.dat};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

The `cycle list` defines the plot specifications for each `\addplot` command without explicit given keys. The first plot uses the first entry in the list, the second uses the second etc.

If you are using `\addplot+[...]` the specifications of the `cycle list` are appended by the explicit given keys. In the example above the color for every plot is specified by the `cycle list` and the plot options are appended by `fill` and `draw=black`.

If you use explicit specifications without the `+` the cycle list is not used. Thats means `\addplot[...]` does not use the cycle list even if the brackets are empty.

Comment: That is a nice solution too and probably I settle for this one. Can you share some insights on what is happening behind the scenes? I am not exaclty sure how the cycle list is connected to the `\addplot+` command. For this example it may be pretty obvious, but I want to make sure to not miss an important detail.

Comment: @Rambo See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to present my personal conclusion of the discussion in the comment section of the question (and the link I posted there).

The following code is a working example which fits my needs:

```
\foreach \x/\barcolor in {1/red, 2/green, 3/blue, 4/gray}{
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[fill=\barcolor]}
    \temp table[x=key,y expr={\thisrowno{\x}/\thisrowno{6}}] {data.dat};
}
```

I think this is a cleaner version of the proposal of egreg, because I was a bit confused by the reuse of `\x` for two different things.