# Use same color for plot and draw in a for-loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot a graph with an asymptotic behaviour inside a for-loop. Since PGFplots is not very good at drawing asymptotes, I would like to help it a little manually. For that I'd like to have my draw command use the same color as the previous plot. Here is an MWE:

```
    \foreach \t in {1,2,5}{
        \addplot+[cycle list name=puOr4,samples=2000, domain=0:6]
        {((x>\t)*0 + ((x<\t)*1/(2*pi*sqrt((\t)^2-(\x)^2))}; %
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:\t,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:\t,0});}
        \temp
        \addlegendentryexpanded{$\tau=\t$};%
    }
```

TL:DR; Currently it looks like this:
[image]

But I would like to have the asymptotes in the same style as the graph, like this:
[image]

---

Accepted answer will either: convince PGFplots (in a nice way) to plot the asymptote or will allow me to use draw with the same style-settings.

Not accepted is the dirty trick to set `samples=202,domain=0:\t*1.001` - which works just fine in this example, but is dirty and not always applicable.

Comment: `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,5}{
        \addplot+[]
        {((x>#1)*0 + ((x<#1)*1/(2*pi*sqrt((#1)^2-(x)^2))} (#1,0) -- ({#1,0} |- {rel axis cs:0,1}) ;%
        \addlegendentry{$\tau=#1$};%
    }`

Comment: Thanks! Almost: `\addplot+[] {((x>#1)*0 + ((x<#1)*1/(2*pi*sqrt((#1)^2-(x)^2))} (axis cs:#1,0) -- ({axis cs:#1,0} |- {rel axis cs:0,1});` -- And you've got it! Want to answer? Maybe explain a little? Because within a normal foreach this doth not work.

Comment: Yes, it's the typical foreach not expanding stuff timely inside a scope : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you again! Will you compose an answer or should I in your name?

Comment: I can't access to TeX right now so please if you have an answer feel free to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @percusse, here's how to do it:

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1.0,2.3,5.0}{
    \addplot+[domain=(#1)*1.001:6.85]%
     {((x>#1)*0 + ((x>#1)*1/(2*pi*sqrt((x)^2-(#1)^2))}%
     (axis cs: #1,0) -- ({axis cs:#1,0} |- {rel axis cs:0,1}) ;%
    \addlegendentry{$r=#1$};%
}
```

or equivalently

```
\foreach \r in {1.0,2.3, 5.0}{
    \edef\temp{%
        \noexpand\addplot+[domain=\r*1.001:6.85]%
         {(\r>x)*0 + (\r<x)*(1/(2*pi*sqrt((x)^2-(\r)^2)))}%
         (axis cs:\r,0) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:\r,0});%
    }
    \temp
    \addlegendentryexpanded{$r=\r$};%
}
```

(Please note, that I switches the roles of t-x and x-r in relation to the question).

[image]

To understand a little why this works: [PGFplots foreach equivalent to TikZ's with multiple variables separated by a slash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla)