# Reading string from CSV in pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a CSV file which contains different sets of plot-data (x1,y1,z1), ..., (xn,yn,zn) and some additional data, one of which I would use as legend.

My current code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots,tikz}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,display columns/setting/.style=string type]{
x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,plotID,setting
-1,2,0.149858,-1,6,0.582841,1,asdasd
-1,8,0.447147,-1,9,0.548643,2,test
}\table

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \pgfplotstablegetcolsof\table
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\plots}{(\pgfplotsretval-2)/3-1}
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\plots} {
                \addplot table[x=x#1,y=z#1] {\table};
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{setting}\of{\table}
                %\edef\bla{\pgfplotsretval}
                %\def\bla{\pgfplotsretval}
                \xdef\bla{\pgfplotsretval}
                \addlegendentry{\bla};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The plotting seems to work fine, howver, adding the legend makes some troubles.
Depending on whether I use `\def`, `\edef` `\xdef` or directly `\pgfplotsretval` for `\addlegendentry`, I get either nothing or just `test` as legend. However, it should show `asdasd` for the first plot and `test` for the second only.

What is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Hubble's discovery, we know that the universe is expanding, and so does `pgfplots`. Here comes a [standard trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17817/121799) to deal with this:

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\addlegendentry{\pgfplotsretval};}
\temp
```

means that in `\temp` `\addlegendentry` is not yet expanded, but `\pgfplotsretval` is. So when the loop is run through for the first time, `\temp` will be `\addlegendentry{asdasd}`. Calling `\temp` now will set the appropriate legend entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots,tikz}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,display columns/setting/.style=string type]{
x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,plotID,setting
-1,2,0.149858,-1,6,0.582841,1,asdasd
-1,8,0.447147,-1,9,0.548643,2,test
}\table

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \pgfplotstablegetcolsof\table
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\plots}{(\pgfplotsretval-2)/3-1}
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\plots} {
                \addplot table[x=x#1,y=z#1] {\table};
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{setting}\of{\table}
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\addlegendentry{\pgfplotsretval};}
                \temp
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]