# Accessing raw meta in pgfplots scatter plots with explicit meta

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to make use of explicit meta data that I add to coordinates in a scatter plots. However, I do not want the transformed data, rather it should be the original one. This question is motivated by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460938/121799), where the raw meta data was to be used to set the node anchors.

**Problem**: Why is there an additional `]` in the end. That is, why is `0` getting mapped to `0Y0.0e0]` rather than `0Y0.0e0`? AFAIK thisextra `]` should not be there, or am I missing something? This thingy makes it very hard to parse the data to get back the original entry.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
poles/.style= { scatter,
        scatter src=explicit, only marks, mark=x, mark size = 1ex, thick},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[% point meta=explicit symbolic, %<- does not help (as expected)
visualization depends on=\pgfplotspointmeta \as \mymeta,
    nodes near coords={\pgfplotspointmeta}, % \pgfplotspointmetatransformed transforms the values
    enlargelimits=0.3]
\addplot[poles] coordinates {(-2,2)[90] (-2,-2)[270] (-8,0)[0]};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I understand that if one was to provide the data in form of a table, the analogous problem would be absent. That is to say that I am not interested in a workaround in which the data is being read from a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were already on the right track: `point meta=explicit symbolic` is what you need.

However, the `polar` style *overrides* this setting by means of `scatter src=explicit`. The key `scatter src` is a legacy alias for `point meta` (it was present before the concept of point meta data was defined in its general form).

The result is thus

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
poles/.style= { scatter,
        only marks, mark=x, mark size = 1ex, thick},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords={\pgfplotspointmeta},
    enlargelimits=0.3]
\addplot[poles] coordinates {(-2,2)[90] (-2,-2)[270] (-8,0)[0]};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have simply not seen this answer. If I had seen it, I would have accepted back then. Sorry!