# Macro based flags for forest tree

Tags: macros, forest

I'm using simple y/n macros as flags in my document to include or exclude certain parts of the overall document (these normally are in a separate "config.tex" file for ease of use). With the forest package, I get strange results when using this approach (using pdftex). The inserted texts seem to be interpreted as text instead of added or non-added leaves.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\newcommand{\AddIf}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{y}}{#2}{#3}}

\newcommand{\hasOptionOne}{y}
\newcommand{\hasOptionFour}{y}

\begin{document}

The user has the following options:
\begin{itemize}
    \AddIf{\hasOptionOne}{\item Option One}{}
    \item Option Two
    \item Option Three
    \AddIf{\hasOptionFour}{\item Option Four}{}
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Available Options}
    \label{fig-available-options}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={draw,align=center},
        forked edges,
        [Main item
            \AddIf{\hasOptionOne}{[Option One]}{}
            [Option Two]
            [Option Three]
            \AddIf{\hasOptionFour}{[Option Four]}{}
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: `forest` has a highly sophisticated and powerful parser. I believe it is practically hopeless to try to trick it this way, You would have to makes sure that `forest` sees the expanded version of these `\AddIf`s, but the way you construct this command, already `\edef\temp{\AddIf{\hasOptionOne}{\item Option One}{}}` fails. So I would like to argue that you should resort to pure `forest` methods to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi marmot. Can you suggest any pure forest methods that can be somehow connected to (possibly differently designed) flags outside the forest environment? I'd be happy to use them, but as I need these flags to be set centrally for the entire document, I'm not sure how to connect these two worlds.

Comment: I added one example. Quite possible that there exist alternatives. (Just for the records, I usually try to avoid using the `ifthen` package because of such issues.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for it... I replaced your command `\AddIf` by some version that can be appropriately expanded. And then a trick is used that has also some [applications in `pgfplots`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17817/121799) and so on. It makes sure that the content of the tree gets expanded first, and then it gets passed to forest.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

% \usepackage{ifthen} % no longer used here
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\newcommand{\Yes}{y}
\newcommand{\AddIf}[3]{\ifx#1\Yes%
#2%
\else
#3%
\fi}

\newcommand{\hasOptionOne}{y}
\newcommand{\hasOptionFour}{y}

\begin{document}

The user has the following options:
\begin{itemize}
    \AddIf{\hasOptionOne}{\item Option One}{}
    \item Option Two
    \item Option Three
    \AddIf{\hasOptionFour}{\item Option Four}{}
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Available Options}
    \label{fig-available-options}
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{forest}
        for tree={draw,align=center},
        forked edges,
        [Main item
            \AddIf{\hasOptionOne}{[Option One]}{}
            [Option Two]
            [Option Three]
            \AddIf{\hasOptionFour}{[Option Four]}{}
        ]
    \noexpand\end{forest}}
    \temp
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that really does the job, thanks for sharing. One additional remark/question: due to the expansion trick, forced line breaks within nodes (\\ or  \newline) cause compilation errors - can this also be overcome somehow?

Comment: @Michael Did you try to replace ` \\` by `\noexpand\\`?

Comment: No, I hadn't tried that. Seems to work. Thanks again.