# What is wrong with my \foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

The code below works fine

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[ 
      ticks = none, axis lines = middle,
      xmin = -5, xmax = 5,
      ymin = -5, ymax = 5,
    ]
    \foreach \p in {1,2}{
        \draw[red] (-5,1)--(5,1);
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, as soon as I try to use the variable `\p` inside the loop, as in

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[ 
      ticks = none, axis lines = middle,
      xmin = -5, xmax = 5,
      ymin = -5, ymax = 5,
    ]
    \foreach \p in {1,2}{
        \draw[red] (-5,\p)--(5,\p);
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get an undefined control sequence error. This persists no matter what I use instead of `\p`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Notice that `pgfplots` does a lot of service in the background, which is why some variantes of `\foreach` may not work in an `axis` environment. These things are explained in detail in section **8.1 Utility Commands** of the pgfplots manual. Long story short for this case: use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[ 
      ticks = none, axis lines = middle,
      xmin = -5, xmax = 5,
      ymin = -5, ymax = 5,
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2}{
        \draw[red] (-5,#1)--(5,#1);
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are situations in which you really want to use the traditional `\foreach` loop. In those you can you can use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17817/121799) to get

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[ 
      ticks = none, axis lines = middle,
      xmin = -5, xmax = 5,
      ymin = -5, ymax = 5,
    ]
    \foreach \p in {1,2}{
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[red] (-5,\p)--(5,\p);}
        \temp
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Side-remark: try to avoid calling the loop variable `\p`, `\n`, `\x` or `\y` if you consider making use of the `calc` library because there these macros have their own meanings.