# Why foreach failed in groupplot in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, loops, groupplots

I know that there are some expansion problem if the `\foreach` command is used in pgfplots' axis environment. I have read the [answer concerning this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla/17817#17817) and I know that the loop variable should be expanded by edef. But after using such a technique, my code still failed.

I'm going to draw some subplot with the help of groupplots library. The data file is d1.dat, d2.dat and so on. So I try to use foreach to plot them. The following is my attempt.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents*}{d1.dat}
1   2
2   3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{d2.dat}
1   3
1.5   0
2   4
\end{filecontents*}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \foreach \x in {1,2}{
        \edef\tmp{\noexpand\addplot table {d\x.dat};}
        \tmp
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group size=1 by 2,
        vertical sep=2cm
    }]
    \nextgroupplot[title=data1]
    \addplot table {d1.dat};
    \nextgroupplot[title=data2]
    \addplot table {d2.dat};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

% \begin{tikzpicture}
% \begin{groupplot}[
%     group style={
%         group size=1 by 2,
%         vertical sep=2cm
%     }
%     ]
%     \foreach \x/\y in {1/data1,2/data2}{
%     \edef\tmp{
%         \noexpand\nextgroupplot[title=\y]
%         \noexpand\addplot table {d\x.dat};
%     }
%     \tmp
%     }
% \end{groupplot}
% \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above code contain three `tikzpicture` environment. In the first `tikzpicture` environment, the `edef` technique is used and it works as expected. In the last `tikzpicture` environment, I still use this method but it failed. I wonder the reason why it failed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\foreach` of these subtleties one can write a separate question and answer. ;-)

Here the issue is that `\foreach` puts the stuff it is iterating over in groups. Ironically, despite their name, `\groupplot`s do not want to be put in groups. So `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` saves the day here.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents*}{d1.dat}
1   2
2   3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{d2.dat}
1   3
1.5   0
2   4
\end{filecontents*}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}

% this fails because the group plots are in group
% 
% \begin{tikzpicture}
% \begin{groupplot}[
%     group style={
%         group size=1 by 2,
%         vertical sep=2cm
%     }]
%     \begingroup\nextgroupplot[title=data1]
%     \addplot table {d1.dat};\endgroup
%     \begingroup\nextgroupplot[title=data2]
%     \addplot table {d2.dat};\endgroup
% \end{groupplot}
% \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group size=1 by 2,
        vertical sep=2cm
    }
    ]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {1,2}{
    \edef\tmp{
        \noexpand\nextgroupplot[title=data\x]
        \noexpand\addplot table {d\x.dat};
    }
    \tmp
    }
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment the commented part, you can verify that putting the `\groupplot`s into groups leads to errors, regardless of `\foreach`.