# Multiple pgfplots addplot commands in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I am trying to build upon the answer of Christian Feuersänger here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17817/193625

Instead of just on `\addplot` I want to have multiple in the body of my loop.
However this results in the error: `Use of \pgffor@scanround doesn't match its definition.`

Can anyone help?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \foreach \x/\l in {-2/a, -1/b, 1/c, 2/d}{
            \edef\temp{\noexpand
                \addplot%
                    coordinates{ (\x, 0.5) (\x, 1) }
                    node [above] {\l};
                % comment the next three lines to make it work
                \addplot%
                    coordinates{ (\x, -0.5) (\x, -1) }
                    node [below] {\l};
            }
            \temp
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can place the second `\addplot` in another `\edef\temp{\noexpand ... }\temp` structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place `\noexpand` before every `\addplot` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \foreach \x/\l in {-2/a, -1/b, 1/c, 2/d}{
            \edef\temp{
                \noexpand\addplot%
                    coordinates{ (\x, 0.5) (\x, 1) }
                    node [above] {\l};
                \noexpand\addplot%
                    coordinates{ (\x, -0.5) (\x, -1) }
                    node [below] {\l};
            }
            \temp
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

You can also nest `\foreach` loops (this may further simplify things, depending on your concrete set up):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \x/\l in {-2/a, -1/b, 1/c, 2/d}{
                \foreach \p/\ya/\yb in {above/0.5/1, below/-0.5/-1}{
                    \edef\temp{
                        \noexpand\addplot%
                            coordinates{ (\x, \ya) (\x, \yb) }
                            node [\p] {\l};
                    }\temp
                }
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both yield:

[image]

Comment: Ty. So simple. It is just that I never really understand how latex works and I cannot make sense of most error messages.